# Class not found on server , workes well on local

Tags: symfony, capifony

I am using symfony2.1 ,github and capfony(for deployment)

When I start the project these combination works very well.

However,Since I added SonataUserBundle and FOSUserbundle to project

> cap deploy

command returns error 
such as

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle' not found in /var/www/html/muty/releases/20130410144941/app/AppKernel.php on line 26

But I have SonataAdminBundle here.

[application name]/vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Sonata/AdminBundle
and 
in AppKernel.php

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
     .....
        new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),
        new Sonata\CacheBundle\SonataCacheBundle(),
        new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
        new Sonata\jQueryBundle\SonatajQueryBundle(),
        new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
        new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
    .....
    );
}
```

These structure works well on local,but can't be deploy

I use composer not vendor.

IMHO,
it seems that  vendor folder is not correctly deployed,am I correct?
or There are other places to check?
please give me ideas!

thanks a lot

My deploy.rb is

```
set :application, "myapplication"
set :domain,      "myapplication"
set :deploy_to,   "/var/www/html/myapplication"
set :app_path,    "app"

set :repository,  "git@github.com:myname/myapplication.git"
set :scm,         :git
# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `subversion`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, or `none`

set :default_shell,         "TERM=dumb sudo -u app /bin/sh"
set :branch, "master"
set :scm_username, "myname"
set :scm_passphrase, "mypass"
set   :use_sudo,      false
set :user, 'app'
set :model_manager, "doctrine"
# Or: `propel`

role :web,        "49.212.***.***"                         # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app,        "49.212.***.***"                         # This may be the same as your     `Web` server
role :db,         "49.212.***.***", :primary => true       # This is where Symfony2     migrations will run

set  :keep_releases,  3
set :clear_controllers,     false #app_dev.php should be deployed
#set :shared_files,        ["app/config/parameters.yml"]
#set :shared_children,     [app_path + "/logs", web_path + "/uploads"]

set :use_composer, true
set :update_vendors, true
set :deploy_via,            :remote_cache

set :writable_dirs,       ["app/cache", "app/logs"]
set :permission_method,   :chown #
set :use_set_permissions, false

# Be more verbose by uncommenting the following line
logger.level = Logger::MAX_LEVEL
```

Comment: Can you check your `vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php` and see if there is `Sonata\\AdminBundle` in the array?

Comment: There is `'Sonata\\AdminBundle' => $vendorDir . '/sonata-project/admin-bundle/'` in autoload_namespaces.php

Comment: paste your deploy.rb file

Comment: I pasted my deploy.rb. thanks.

Comment: @whitebear, I am having a similar issue. I get the error whenever I do `composer update` `Sonata\\AdminBundle ...` is not in autoload_namespaces.php ... What does this indicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that `SonataAdminBundle` isn't installed by the time composer tries to interact with your application (most likely warming up cache), which triggers the error.

First thing to try is to add `vendor` to `shared_children`, like this:

> set :shared_children,    [app_path + "/logs", web_path + "/uploads", "vendor"]

Second, updating vendors every time you deploy might not be a good idea (and could actually cause the problem because of incompatible dependencies):

> set :update_vendors,    false

If both of those fail, try to deploy from scratch to a new folder (with settings above) and see if it throws any errors.

Comment: it solved my problem!I dont know why my vendor directory was not updated(maybe cache related as you told though.....).thanks a lot!!!Finally I can deploy!